# Is using NEXT_PUBLIC for my secret key is a dangerous way to use environment variables when I deploy on vercel?

Tags: environment-variables, vercel, openai-api

I am trying to use ChatGPT API to build a Chatbot with Next.js and deploy on Vercel.

In local development environment everything worked perfectly but the problem occured when I deployed.

The log from Vercel said that it can not find the API Key for my ChatGPT API

Eventhough I have set my environment variable in deployment settings on Vercel it was not working.

The solution I have figured out was change API key name from OPEN_API_KEY -> NEXT_PUBLIC_OPEN_API_KEY

However I am worrying that my secret key can be exposed in public.

Is my solution a safe way to use? If it's not please provide me other possible solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.